# Multiple pages according to the height of the viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a project in which I need to set up an auto-paginated according to the height of the viewport.

Should not appear the vertical scroll. If the content exceeds the height should begin automatic paginate.

The content would be several paragraphs (50 to 100) within a div tag. These paragraphs are the ones who should fit in paging.

Is there a plugin for jQuery to do this?

Or some other solution that adapts to different screen sizes ...

Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score -1):

I hope any of these plugins might be useful.

- [jQuery ScrollPagination](http://andersonferminiano.com/jqueryscrollpagination/)
- [Screw – A jQuery Plugin](http://jasonlau.biz/home/jquery/screw-a-jquery-plugin)
- [Scroll Extend Plugin](http://contextllc.com/tools/jQuery-infinite-scroll-live-scroll)
- [Infinite Scroll Plugin](http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/02/24/create-infinte-scroll-effect-using-jquery-with-demo/)
- [Endless Scroll Plugin](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/load-content-while-scrolling-with-jquery/)
- [Triggered Infinite Scroll](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/infinite-scroll-jquery-plugin/)
- [Infinite Ajax Scroll, a jQuery Plugin](http://www.fieg.nl/infinite-ajax-scroll-a-jquery-plugin)

[Reference](http://designbeep.com/2011/08/12/12-jquery-infinite-scrollingscroll-read-plugins-for-content-navigation/)

Comment: I need something like this: http://blog.creonfx.com/examples/javascript/custom-pager.html but with jQuery. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Did you checkout those plugins?